# camera UIImagePickerController shows black screen in device ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, device

I am try below code to capture Image through camera. This code is working fine in all device below the iPhone 6
This code is not working in iPHone6 and iPhone6+. It show a black screen.

```
enter code here

 (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0: NSLog(@"Photo Butten Clicked");
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [App_Delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
            //            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
            break;

        case 1: NSLog(@"Camera Butten Clicked");
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
             [App_Delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
            // [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution. I just replace 
below code

```
[App_Delegate.window.rootViewController 
        presentViewController:picker 
        animated:YES 
        completion:nil];
```

with this code

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

### You just change setting of you device

#### Follow these steps

1) Go to device settings.

2) Find your application in setting list.

3) And give camera access permission to your application (under allow "app name" to access).