# How to identify the camera is black screen or normal

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm doing one application. In that, I'm taking the image from the camera. But, one device camera app itself is showing the black screen for rear, and when I open the camera from my application also showing the black screen for rear. So, to identify the camera black screen and restrict the user to stop using the camera in my application.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391026/camera-uiimagepickercontroller-shows-black-screen-in-device-ios8

Comment: Did the same thing already, default camera app also not working.

Comment: I am not getting your question. Are you saying that you want to restrict user from accessing there camera?

Comment: One of my device, showing black screen when i open default camera due to some some problem in device.So now i have to check camera is showing black screen or normal screen in my application.